# unity3d cant open port

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, robotics

I'm trying to control my Dynamixel AX-12+ servo using unity3d, using the dynamixel SDK (C#). the servo is connected to my windows 10 pc using a u2d2 (not an Arduino!) and it works fine using visual studio. I imported the dll to unity and wrote a script for controlling the servomotor and there are no errors in the script but when I try to run it, it fails to open the port and after that, the visual studio code also fails to open the port (until i disconnect and reconnect the USB).

the part of the code trying to open the port:

```
  // Open port (COM9)
  if (dynamixel.openPort(port_num))
  {
    Debug.Log("Succeeded to open the port!");
  }
  else
  {
    Debug.Log("Failed to open the port!");
    
  }
```

i used the example SDK codes to see if the motor works correctly with visual studio [(like this one)](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/software/dynamixel/dynamixel_sdk/sample_code/csharp_read_write_protocol_1_0/#csharp-read-write-protocol-10)

a complete unity script :

```
    using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace dynamixelunity {
    
    //further below you can find the "DynamixelObject" class.
    public class dynamixel : MonoBehaviour
      {
        const string dll_path = "dxl_x64_c";

        #region PortHandler
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern int    portHandler         (string port_name);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern bool   openPort            (int port_num);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   closePort           (int port_num);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   clearPort           (int port_num);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   setPortName         (int port_num, string port_name);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern string getPortName         (int port_num);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern bool   setBaudRate         (int port_num, int baudrate);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern int    getBaudRate         (int port_num);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern int    readPort            (int port_num, byte[] packet, int length);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern int    writePort           (int port_num, byte[] packet, int length);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   setPacketTimeout    (int port_num, UInt16 packet_length);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   setPacketTimeoutMSec(int port_num, double msec);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern bool   isPacketTimeout     (int port_num);
        #endregion

        #region PacketHandler
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   packetHandler       ();

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern IntPtr getTxRxResult       (int protocol_version, int result);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern IntPtr getRxPacketError    (int protocol_version, byte error);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern int    getLastTxRxResult   (int port_num, int protocol_version);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern byte   getLastRxPacketError(int port_num, int protocol_version);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   setDataWrite        (int port_num, int protocol_version, UInt16 data_length, UInt16 data_pos, UInt32 data);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern UInt32 getDataRead         (int port_num, int protocol_version, UInt16 data_length, UInt16 data_pos);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   txPacket            (int port_num, int protocol_version);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   rxPacket            (int port_num, int protocol_version);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   txRxPacket          (int port_num, int protocol_version);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   ping                (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern UInt16 pingGetModelNum     (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   broadcastPing       (int port_num, int protocol_version);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern bool   getBroadcastPingResult(int port_num, int protocol_version, int id);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   reboot              (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   factoryReset        (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, byte option);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   readTx              (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address, UInt16 length);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   readRx              (int port_num, int protocol_version, UInt16 length);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   readTxRx            (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address, UInt16 length);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   read1ByteTx         (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern byte   read1ByteRx         (int port_num, int protocol_version);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern byte   read1ByteTxRx       (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   read2ByteTx         (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern UInt16 read2ByteRx         (int port_num, int protocol_version);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern UInt16 read2ByteTxRx       (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   read4ByteTx         (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern UInt32 read4ByteRx         (int port_num, int protocol_version);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern UInt32 read4ByteTxRx       (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   writeTxOnly         (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address, UInt16 length);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   writeTxRx           (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address, UInt16 length);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   write1ByteTxOnly    (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address, byte data);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   write1ByteTxRx      (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address, byte data);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   write2ByteTxOnly    (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address, UInt16 data);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   write2ByteTxRx      (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address, UInt16 data);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   write4ByteTxOnly    (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address, UInt32 data);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   write4ByteTxRx      (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address, UInt32 data);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   regWriteTxOnly      (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address, UInt16 length);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   regWriteTxRx        (int port_num, int protocol_version, byte id, UInt16 address, UInt16 length);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   syncReadTx          (int port_num, int protocol_version, UInt16 start_address, UInt16 data_length, UInt16 param_length);
        // syncReadRx   -> GroupSyncRead
        // syncReadTxRx -> GroupSyncRead

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   syncWriteTxOnly     (int port_num, int protocol_version, UInt16 start_address, UInt16 data_length, UInt16 param_length);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   bulkReadTx          (int port_num, int protocol_version, UInt16 param_length);
        // bulkReadRx   -> GroupBulkRead
        // bulkReadTxRx -> GroupBulkRead

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   bulkWriteTxOnly     (int port_num, int protocol_version, UInt16 param_length);
        #endregion

        #region GroupBulkRead
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern int    groupBulkRead       (int port_num, int protocol_version);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern bool   groupBulkReadAddParam   (int group_num, byte id, UInt16 start_address, UInt16 data_length);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   groupBulkReadRemoveParam(int group_num, byte id);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   groupBulkReadClearParam (int group_num);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   groupBulkReadTxPacket   (int group_num);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   groupBulkReadRxPacket   (int group_num);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   groupBulkReadTxRxPacket (int group_num);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern bool   groupBulkReadIsAvailable(int group_num, byte id, UInt16 address, UInt16 data_length);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern UInt32 groupBulkReadGetData    (int group_num, byte id, UInt16 address, UInt16 data_length);
        #endregion

        #region GroupBulkWrite
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern int    groupBulkWrite            (int port_num, int protocol_version);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern bool   groupBulkWriteAddParam    (int group_num, byte id, UInt16 start_address, UInt16 data_length, UInt32 data, UInt16 input_length);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   groupBulkWriteRemoveParam (int group_num, byte id);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern bool   groupBulkWriteChangeParam (int group_num, byte id, UInt16 start_address, UInt16 data_length, UInt32 data, UInt16 input_length, UInt16 data_pos);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   groupBulkWriteClearParam  (int group_num);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   groupBulkWriteTxPacket    (int group_num);
        #endregion

        #region GroupSyncRead
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern int    groupSyncRead             (int port_num, int protocol_version, UInt16 start_address, UInt16 data_length);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern bool   groupSyncReadAddParam     (int group_num, byte id);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   groupSyncReadRemoveParam  (int group_num, byte id);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   groupSyncReadClearParam   (int group_num);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   groupSyncReadTxPacket     (int group_num);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   groupSyncReadRxPacket     (int group_num);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   groupSyncReadTxRxPacket   (int group_num);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern bool   groupSyncReadIsAvailable  (int group_num, byte id, UInt16 address, UInt16 data_length);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern UInt32 groupSyncReadGetData      (int group_num, byte id, UInt16 address, UInt16 data_length);
        #endregion

        #region GroupSyncWrite
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern int    groupSyncWrite            (int port_num, int protocol_version, UInt16 start_address, UInt16 data_length);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern bool   groupSyncWriteAddParam    (int group_num, byte id, UInt32 data, UInt16 data_length);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   groupSyncWriteRemoveParam (int group_num, byte id);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern bool   groupSyncWriteChangeParam (int group_num, byte id, UInt32 data, UInt16 data_length, UInt16 data_pos);
        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   groupSyncWriteClearParam  (int group_num);

        [DllImport(dll_path)]
        public static extern void   groupSyncWriteTxPacket    (int group_num);
        #endregion
      }



    public class DynamixelObject : MonoBehaviour {

        // Control table address
        public const int ADDR_MX_TORQUE_ENABLE           = 24;                  // Control table address is different in Dynamixel model
        public const int ADDR_MX_GOAL_POSITION           = 30;
        public const int ADDR_MX_PRESENT_POSITION        = 36;

        // Protocol version
        public const int PROTOCOL_VERSION                = 1;                   // See which protocol version is used in the Dynamixel

        // Default setting
        public const int DXL_ID                          = 1;                   // Dynamixel ID: 1 
        public const int BAUDRATE                        = 1000000;
        public const string DEVICENAME                   = "COM9";              // Check which port is being used on your controller
                                                                                // ex) Windows: "COM1"   Linux: "/dev/ttyUSB0" Mac: "/dev/tty.usbserial-*"

        public const int TORQUE_ENABLE                   = 1;                   // Value for enabling the torque
        public const int TORQUE_DISABLE                  = 0;                   // Value for disabling the torque
        public const int DXL_MINIMUM_POSITION_VALUE      = 100;                 // Dynamixel will rotate between this value
        public const int DXL_MAXIMUM_POSITION_VALUE      = 4000;                // and this value (note that the Dynamixel would not move when the position value is out of movable range. s
        public const int DXL_MOVING_STATUS_THRESHOLD     = 10;                  // Dynamixel moving status threshold

        public const byte ESC_ASCII_VALUE                = 0x1b;

        public const int COMM_SUCCESS                    = 0;                   // Communication Success result value
        public const int COMM_TX_FAIL                    = -1001;               // Communication Tx Failed

        // Initialize PortHandler Structs
          // Set the port path
          // Get methods and members of PortHandlerLinux or PortHandlerWindows
          
        int port_num = dynamixel.portHandler(DEVICENAME);
        
        void start(){
            

          // Initialize PacketHandler Structs
          dynamixel.packetHandler();

          int index = 0;
          int dxl_comm_result = COMM_TX_FAIL;                                   // Communication result
          UInt16[] dxl_goal_position = new UInt16[2]{ DXL_MINIMUM_POSITION_VALUE, DXL_MAXIMUM_POSITION_VALUE };         // Goal position

          byte dxl_error = 0;                                                   // Dynamixel error
          UInt16 dxl_present_position = 0;                                      // Present position

          // Open port (COM9)
          if (dynamixel.openPort(port_num))
          {
            Debug.Log("Succeeded to open the port!");
          }
          else
          {
            Debug.Log("Failed to open the port!");

          }

          // Set port baudrate
          if (dynamixel.setBaudRate(port_num, BAUDRATE))
          {
            Debug.Log("Succeeded to change the baudrate!");
          }
          else
          {
            Debug.Log("Failed to change the baudrate!");
          }

        }
        
        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                //Enable motor torque
                dynamixel.write1ByteTxRx(port_num, PROTOCOL_VERSION, DXL_ID, ADDR_MX_TORQUE_ENABLE, TORQUE_ENABLE);
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                //disable motor torque
                dynamixel.write1ByteTxRx(port_num, PROTOCOL_VERSION, DXL_ID, ADDR_MX_TORQUE_ENABLE, TORQUE_DISABLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What driver are you using?  Always use the vendor usb driver and not the standard Microsoft driver.

Comment: Can you show us the exact script you used in unity and also the exact script you used with visual studio only?

Comment: @A.Gerber the exact scripts i used in visual studio to are the sample codes of the SDK , i will add my unity script to the main question.

Comment: @jdweng I think its the standard Microsoft driver that I'm using but there is a Dynamixel wizard app that can detect and control the motor so i don't think the driver is the problem.

Comment: Look for window driver on this page : https://www.trossenrobotics.com/robotis-bioloid-usb2dynamixel.aspx

Comment: @jdweng thanks for sharing that, i followed the instructions there but unfortunately i still have the problem with unity.

Comment: Did you see following on link : USB2DYNAMIXELs purchased before July 2015 may not work with the latest FTDI drivers 2.12.00. For a fix, please see our blog post on the matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out what was wrong!
I forgot to close the port after exiting unity's play mode.
the code below closes the port after exiting play mode:

```
    [InitializeOnLoad]
public static class PlayStateNotifier
{

    static PlayStateNotifier()
    {
        EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged += ModeChanged;
    }

    static void ModeChanged(PlayModeStateChange playModeState)
    {
        if (playModeState == PlayModeStateChange.EnteredEditMode)
        {
            Debug.Log("Entered Edit mode.");
            Debug.Log("Closing dynamixel port! :D");
            dynamixel.closePort(DynamixelObject.port_num);
        }
    }
}
```